# mysqldump for older mysql version

Tags: mysql

Are there any known risks if I use mysqldump tool to backup MySql databases older versions? For example, if I use  mysqldump 5.6 on a production machine to backup MySql 5.X databases.

Comment: There is the issue: http://blog.teamextension.com/mysqldump-couldnt-execute-select-gtid_mode-unknown-system-variable-gtid_mode-1193-1246

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never met such problems. All higher versions support previous ones. So, you can use mysqldump 5.6 for 5.X.

I think you should look at mysqldump options, some of them were added in 5.5, some in 5.6; but the major of options work for all versions.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 5):

There is a option for compatible.  I found it from
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html

> --compatible=name
>
> Produce output that is more compatible with other database systems or
>   with older MySQL servers. The value of name can be ansi, mysql323,
>   mysql40, postgresql, oracle, mssql, db2, maxdb, no_key_options,
>   no_table_options, or no_field_options. To use several values, separate
>   them by commas. These values have the same meaning as the
>   corresponding options for setting the server SQL mode. See Section
>   5.1.8, “Server SQL Modes”.
>
> This option does not guarantee compatibility with other servers. It
>   only enables those SQL mode values that are currently available for
>   making dump output more compatible. For example, --compatible=oracle
>   does not map data types to Oracle types or use Oracle comment syntax.
>
> This option requires a server version of 4.1.0 or higher. With older
>   servers, it does nothing.